# What am I doing wrong? Testbench not updating correctly

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus, intel-fpga

I am trying to implement the testbench so that after 3 ticks, each input gets the new specified valued. For example, first 3 seconds (or ticks) A = 10, B = 0, and then the next 3 seconds (3 seconds to 6 seconds) A = 10, B = 16 and etc. However, on my actual testbench, the values aren't updating the way I want. Am I getting the syntax wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the current values I am getting. I drew the red lines at the top to represent every 3 ticks.

https://gyazo.com/f2c0cddc192d0d6734c98334cd377f12

```
module ALU_tb();

reg [63:0] A, B;
reg [4:0] FS;
reg cin;

wire cout;
wire [63:0] result;
wire [3:0] status;


     
     Final_ALU dut (
     .A(A),
     .B(B),
     .FS(FS),
     .cin(cin),
     .cout(cout),
     .result(result),
     .status(status)
                    );

initial begin //A+1 //A=10 B=0
A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
FS <= 5'b01000;
cin <= 1'b1;
end

always begin //A+B //A=10 B=16
#3
A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000;
FS <= 5'b01000;
cin <= 1'd0;
#3;
end

always begin //A-B //A=10 B=16
#6
A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000;
FS <= 5'b01001;
cin <= 1'd1;
#6; 
end

always begin //A-1 //A=10 , B=1
#9
A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
FS <= 5'b01001;
cin <= 1'd1;
#9; 
end

always begin //-A //A=10 , B=0 (just twos complement of A)
#12
A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
FS <= 5'b01010;
cin <= 1'd1;
#12; 
end


initial begin
#30 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not make assignments to the same signal from multiple `always` blocks.

One way to fix the problem is to use a `fork/join` inside an `initial` block, and get rid of the `always` keywords.  This makes minimal changes to your code:

```
initial begin
    fork
        begin //A+1 //A=10 B=0
        A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
        B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
        FS <= 5'b01000;
        cin <= 1'b1;
        end

        begin //A+B //A=10 B=16
        #3
        A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
        B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000;
        FS <= 5'b01000;
        cin <= 1'd0;
        #3;
        end

        begin //A-B //A=10 B=16
        #6
        A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
        B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000;
        FS <= 5'b01001;
        cin <= 1'd1;
        #6; 
        end

        begin //A-1 //A=10 , B=1
        #9
        A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
        B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
        FS <= 5'b01001;
        cin <= 1'd1;
        #9; 
        end

        begin //-A //A=10 , B=0 (just twos complement of A)
        #12
        A <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010;
        B <= 64'b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
        FS <= 5'b01010;
        cin <= 1'd1;
        #12; 
        end
    join
end
```

A more traditional approach would be to get rid of the `fork`, and just drive all the groups of signals in sequence inside the `initial` block.  Then you would have to adjust all your `#` delays accordingly.